# Blockchain with BigData

Tags: blockchain

We have a requirement where in we need to connect blockchain with nosql databases like DataStax graph db. Is there any pointer for this or any high level idea of how I can achieve this

Answer (score 2):

The general approach to connecting off-chain data stores is storing a hash reference to the data item in the NoSQL DB in a blockchain transaction (in addition to the NoSQL ID or something like that). That ensures integrity of the off-chain data. In future transactions you might update that hash reference to correspond to an updated version of the NoSQL data.

An example of a more integrated approach is for example [BigchainDB](https://www.bigchaindb.com/). BigchainDB runs a Tendermint-based blockchain and a MongoDB instance in parallel.